# How to call .addfilter() while migrating from jetty 7 to jetty 8?

Tags: java, migration, jetty

I am in process of migrating jetty 7 to jetty 8,
I am getting this error:

> no suitable method found for
>   addFilter(Class,String,int)
>       servletContext.addFilter(JsonTokenFilter.class, "/*", FilterMapping.REQUEST);

What I am trying to do is:

```
 // servlet context
ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);

// set session manager
SessionHandler sessionHandler = new GatewaySessionHandler(sessionManager);
servletContext.setSessionHandler(sessionHandler);
sessionHandler.addEventListener(new SessionListener());
sessionHandler.addEventListener(new CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener());
sessionManager.setSecureRequestOnly(Utilities.getConfigBoolean("fievel.jetty.secureCookies", true));
sessionManager.setHttpOnly(Utilities.getConfigBoolean(  "fievel.jetty.httpCookies", true));
setSessionSettings();

// add json rpc signal if session token invalid
servletContext.addFilter(JsonTokenFilter.class, "/*", FilterMapping.REQUEST);
```

The last line is the one that is giving error.

If I refer [ServletContextHandler](http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/8.0.0.v20110901/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html) for jetty 8,

```
addFilter(FilterHolder holder, String pathSpec, EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatches)
```

is ideally the type of code that I should write.

Can anybody give me a clue where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should be writing something like this:

```
servletContext.addFilter(JsonTokenFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
```

since it expects an EnumSet instead of int

I've tried the tutorial from [eclipse jetty tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContext.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(servletContext);

    servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/*");

    servletContext.addFilter(TestFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

the output is:

```
2016-08-10 15:13:58.054:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.19.v20160209
TestFilter Init
2016-08-10 15:13:58.186:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
TestFilter doFilter running
```

so the filter is registered for sure in this way

Comment: If I add above code like, servletContext.addFilter(JsonTokenFilter.class,  "/*", EnumSet.of(FilterMapping.REQUEST)); it gives me : cannot invoke of(int) on the primitive type int

Comment: instead of FilterMapping.REQUEST try to use **DispatcherType.REQUEST**

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterMapping is a class to be used, DispacherType does not resolve into any variable.

Comment: the document you mentioned about ServletContextHandler points to DispatcherType, located here: [DispatcherType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/DispatcherType.html?is-external=true) so you need that in your classpath, if using maven make sure you have dependency to **servlet-api**

Comment: Yes I added servlet 3.0 in classpath and imported DispatcherType. Still EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST) is giving error that, "Cannot invoke (DispatcherType) on primitive type int".

Comment: Make sure you are using *only* Servlet 3.0 on your classpath, that its the final release (not a draft version), and that you are using it on Java 1.7+.   Ideally you should be using Jetty 9 (as Jetty 8 is EOL/End of Life now).

Comment: just updated the answer with a working example, TestFilter just prints out as in the output